# What is the mechanism of Google Sheet displaying large amount of data within shot amount of time

Tags: google-sheets

I'm kind of curious, about how the Google sheet displays thousands of rows of data in a such short amount of time. What they use to deliver such a high-speed data loading system.

Can anyone explain their tactics how do they do that? It would be a great help.

Thanks to all

Comment: Do you mean how [Sheets](https://www.google.es/intl/es/sheets/about/) or [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api) works?

Comment: The Google Sheet not sheet api